# Mobile e2e testing using the official Webdriver Javascript client API

Tags: javascript, testing, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, appium

The [Appium documentation](http://appium.io/slate/en/master/?javascript#list-of-client-libraries-with-appium-server-support) mentions the [wd.js](https://github.com/admc/wd) Webdriver Javascript bindings, and not the [official bindings](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/javascript/index.html).

While Appium is client-agnostic and can be used with both clients, wd.js offers many mobile-specific methods (touch, shake, etc.) which seem to be missing from the official bindings. There is a [mobile Json Wire protocol](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/spec-draft.md?repo=mobile) on the way, but it doesn't seem to have been implemented with the official bindings.

As such, wd.js is required if I want desktop and mobile e2e testing with Appium. However I think the official bindings are far superior.

There is also a [mobile gesture API](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/AdvancedUserInteractions) but I am not sure how much if it has been full implemented by most Selenium servers.

My question is: is it possible to achieve mobile testing (including tapping, etc.) with the official Webdriverjs bindings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appium can be replaced by [Selendroid](http://selendroid.io/) and [ios-driver](http://ios-driver.github.io/ios-driver/) which support the official Javascript bindings.

Answer (score 0):

You can use RemoteWebDriver bindings instead of wd.js bindings with appium.